# What condition can I use in this case for selenium to stop scrolling?

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium, web-scraping, nokogiri

first english is not my mother tongue, sorry if anything is written in a weird way. Right now I'm trying so scrape instagram for a uni challenge. I'm trying to obtain all the pics of any instagram profile, but right now I can only obtain a few.

For scrolling I hardcoded a few **js** scrolls.

```ruby
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
sleep 1
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
sleep 1
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
sleep 2
```

I tried to use the length of **images** vs the total of posts, but if I keep scrolling the length stays the same.

```ruby
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
sleep 1
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
sleep 1
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
sleep 2


doc = Nokogiri::HTML(driver.page_source)

#finding direct link to each pic
arr = doc.search('img').map(&:values)

#cleaning data
images = cleaning_images_data(arr)
#printing images total
p images.length #12

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
sleep 1
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
sleep 1
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
sleep 2

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(driver.page_source)

arr = doc.search('img').map(&:values)

images = cleaning_images_data(arr)

#printing images total
p images.length #12
```

This is the code if anyone want to take a look https://pastebin.com/4BQ2PGPf

Thanks in advance for taking the time to look at my problem.

Comment: So you've shared your code, but you haven't actually said what's the problem with it. I'm afraid we can't just tell you the condition to stop scrolling, if we don't actually know what you _want_ to happen.

Comment: I'm sorry If the question wasn't clear. I'm trying to obtain all the pics of any instagram profile, so I wan to keep scrolling until all the links are available. But If I keep scrolling using this method the link count stays the same.

Comment: If it is the same number of images, does that mean you have found all of them? I'd recommend running your code line by line in console to see what's happening.

Comment: No, the are tons missing, but the data don't change, if I keep scrolling.

Comment: Oh, I see what's going on. You're using `doc = Nokogiri::HTML(driver.page_source)` and then parsing that for the images. But the "page source" probably isn't updating when you call that JS to scroll. Try using Selenium methods to check the images count, not Nokogiri.